# While loop to get even numbers in a list

Tags: python-2.7

1) What am I doing wrong. I want to get the even numbers in the list.

```
L = [5,10, 15, 20, 25]
i = 0
while L[i] % 2 == 0 and i < len(L):
    print L[i]
    i += 1
```

This doesn't give me anything

2) If i run it with `L = [10, 15, 20, 25]` it works but only returns `10`. Why is it not returning `20` as well does while loop stops after first match.

Comment: You might also want to consider the more Pythonic `for elem in lst: if elem % 2 == 0: print(elem)` instead of mucking about with indexes unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put the check condition in the `while` loop. The `while` loop will only run when the condition is true, but once `L[i] = 15` then `15 % 2 == 0` is false, so the `while` loop breaks. The first loop doesn't run at all because the first condition `L[i] % 2 == 0` is false as `L[i] = 5`. You want to use an `if` statement so your code would look like this

```
l = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    if l[i] % 2 == 0:
        print(l[i])
    i += 1
```

However, it would be better to use a `for` loop like this

```
l = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
for i in l:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Actually, it's the `5` that causes the loop exit rather than the `15`, hence the total lack of output. But, other than that minor nitpick, good answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo For the second loop it's the `15`, but I'll add language to clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was guessing thats the case when the loop breaks it doesnt do anything else.I would do it with 'for' but i was doing an assignment where i needed to use it with while. But thanks for the explanation.

Comment: By the way, @Kingston, if you liked the answer you can accept it! It gives you +2 reputation. You can read more about accepting answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).